# Changing the UISprite tint color during runtime with NGUI not working

Tags: unity-game-engine, ngui

I have following code try to change to tint color of a UISprite to indicts an error, I could see the tint color has been changed to red in the inspector, but sprite in the scene kept unchanged, What Have I done wrong?

```
 private void ShowErr(string errMsg)
    {
        gameObject.GetComponent<UIWidget>().color = Color.red;
        //gameObject.GetComponent<UISprite>().color = Color.green;
        transform.GetChild(0).gameObject.SetActive(true);
        transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(0).GetComponent<UILabel>().text = errMsg;
    }
```

[image]

Following was the screenshot of the play scene, note that the sprite(which is the dashed border) kept the origin color but not red as expected.

[image]

Have tried to change the color with `UIWidget` and `UISprite` both works with the inspector but not the game scene.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your sprite to be white instead of black, then you could set color.